# XLS2XXLSX: No module named 'currency-symbols'

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the `xls2xlsx` module to convert several .xls files to .xlsx format, but I get the following error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'currency-symbols'

The code:

```
import os
from xls2xlsx import XLS2XLSX
path = r'./ammcfiles'
p = os.listdir(path)
for f in p:
    if f.endswith('.xlsx'):
        x2x = XLS2XLSX(f)
        x2x.to_xlsx(f)
```

I tried pip installing the module, but it didn't solve the problem.

My Python version is 3.10.4.

Answer (score 1):

Note: More of the stacktrace would have been helpful to see the full issue.

Had a similar issue with a script that was developed and previously run with Python 3.6.

Running the script in Python 3.10 returned the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "<virtual env>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xls2xlsx/htmlxls2xlsx.py", line 37, in 
> import currency_symbols.constants as currency_symbols_constant
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'currency_symbols.constants'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/script/./script.py", line 20, in 
> from xls2xlsx import XLS2XLSX
>
> File "<virtual env>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xls2xlsx/**init**.py", line 3, in 
> from .htmlxls2xlsx import HTMLXLS2XLSX
> File "<virtual env>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xls2xlsx/htmlxls2xlsx.py", line 40, in 
> currency_symbols_constants = importlib.import_module('currency-symbols.constants')
> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'currency-symbols'

#### Investigation

Ensure the packages are installed

```
python -m pip install xls2xlsx currency-symbols
```

Lines 36-40 of `<virtual env>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xls2xlsx/htmlxls2xlsx.py`

```
try:
  import currency_symbols.constants as currency_symbols_constants
except Exception:
  import importlib
  currency_symbols_constants = importlib.import_module('currency-symbols.constants')
```

This code seems to be responsible for loading the `currency-symbols` module regardless of the Python version and by extension the module version.

Therefore, the original error was received because both import attempts failed.

`<virtual env>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/currency_symbols/` contains the file
`_constants.py` and not `constants.py`.

Note the folder is `currency_symbols` and not `currency-symbols`, underscore (`_`) vs dash (`-`). Therefore, `htmlxls2xlsx.py` is using the new `currency-symbols` module name `currency_symbols` but not the new name of the `constants` sub module `_constants`

#### Fix

Edit `htmlxls2xlsx.py` to use `_constants.py`
try:
import currency_symbols._constants as currency_symbols_constants

This fixes the import and usage issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Yuli L mentioned, inside the htmlxls2xlsx.py which is in xls2xlsx module directory I found next:

```
import currency_symbols.constants as currency_symbols_constants
```

And change by (take care with typos):

```
import currency_symbols._constants as currency_symbols_constants
```

[image]